# laravel 5.1 concat multiple column from relationship with eagerloading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I would to CONCAT multiple column name(from different relations) using Model::with(relationships) way. How we can do that.

**Level**

```
id | name
1  | Admin
```

**Permission**

```
id | name
1  | All
```

**User**

```
id | level_id | permission_id | name 
1  | 1        | 1             | Bob Login
```

I tried this way, but not working, I want this output Bob Login, Admin, All

```
User::with(['level','permission'])
   ->selectRaw("CONCATE (user.name, ', ', level.name,', ',permission.name) AS uname")
   ->list('uname','id')->all();
```

---

this way is working, but I dont want this one

```
    DB::table('user AS u')
            ->join('level AS l','u.level_id','=','l.id')
            ->join('permission AS p','u.permission_id','=','p.id')
            ->selectRaw("CONCATE (user.name, ', ', level.name,', ',permission.name) AS uname")
            ->lists('uname','id');
```

Comment: i hate to say this, but adding an attribute to model might had unexpected results when you call `->update()`. also, as by the [api docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_with) `::with()` will return [eloquent builder](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) which didn't have `->selectRaw()`. while your `DB::table()` will have a [query builder](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_selectRaw). however, i am interested if anyone had ideas on how to do what you want.

Comment: @Tezla I need above scenario just for selection, not for update/delete. lets hope for the best :)

Comment: What about using https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust or https://github.com/romanbican/roles

Comment: @Kyslik this was just an example, actually I want it for another thing, 
Like, Medicine Name, Syrup, 125-ML